# What is a test of independence?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, definition

I need to define what a test of independence is, without the use of heavily statistic terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by defining what you mean by independence. For example,

> If two variables are independent this
>   means that knowing the value of one
>   variable does not tell you anything
>   about the value of the other variable.

Then I would describe the test:

> To test for independence we construct
>   a table of values that we would expect
>   to see if the variables were
>   independent. If we observed something
>   "very" different from these expected
>   values, we would conclude that the
>   variables are unlikely to be independent.

Comment: It rather does not change your knowledge about distribution of other variable. Definition of independence: P(Y|X)=P(Y). We know value of other variable only in rare cases of perfect prediction (correlation equals 1 or -1).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you take the definition of wikipedia. It's quite short und doesn't use heavily statistic terms.

> A test of independence assesses whether paired observations on two variables, expressed in a contingency table, are independent of each other – for example, whether people from different regions differ in the frequency with which they report that they support a political candidate.